# C program with struct and fgets

Tags: c, string, structure

I want to make a program with struct which prints out the data of a film entered by the user.  The program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct films {
  char title[100];
  int length;
  char genre[100];
};

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  struct films film[100];
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("%d. film:\n", i+1);
    printf("Title: ");
    fgets(film[i].title,100,stdin);
    printf("Lenght: ");
    scanf("%d",&film[i].length);
    printf("Mufaj: ");
    fgets(film[i].genre,100,stdin);
  }
  printf("The films: \n");
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("The %d.film:[%s:%d:%s] ", i+1 , film[i].title, film[i].length, film[i].genre);
  return 0;
}
```

I made a mistake at `fgets`, but I don't know what should I do to make it right.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hello Tyler please provide some more explanation about what does not work or what errors occur with the exact error message texts. Otherwise this is a "Look at my code and fix it" post instead of "help me to resolve this specific problem i can not figure out"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you mix `fgets` with `scanf`.

After the `scanf` call to read the length, there's a newline left in the input buffer.  On the following call to `fgets`, it reads just that newline.

Replace the `scanf` call with a call to `fgets` using a temporary string followed by `sscanf`:

```
char line[100];
fgets(line, 100, stdin);
sscanf(line, "%d",&film[i].length);
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to correct my problem.

Comment: @TylerJoe Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, besides what @dbush mentioned, is to consume all characters after scanning for an integer:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
while(getchar() != '\n')
    continue;

printf("Lenght: ");
scanf("%d",&film[i].length);
while(getchar() != '\n')
    continue;
```

The problem is, after `scanf` reads an integer value, the `\n'` is left in the input stream.  A subsequent call to `fgets` reads the '\n' and returns.

Another problem you have is that `fgets` leaves the `\n` in the string.  When you print out the data later you get something like this:

```
$ ./main.exe
1
1. film:
Title: one
Lenght: 2
Mufaj: three
The films:
The 1.film:[one
:2:three
]
```

To resolve this issue, you can use `strchr` in `string.h`.  For example:

```
char *ch = strchr(film[i].title, '\n');
if(ch != NULL)
    ch[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: Note that `while(getchar() != '\n')
    continue;` is an infinite loop on `stdin` end-of-file.

Comment: Thank you for  your solution, I will keep it in mind, it helped!